# How to properly use the Between statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SQL SERVER:

Select tblActivity.RoomID, tblActivity.Time , tblRoom.RoomType
from tblActivity
Inner Join tblRoom
On tblRoom.ID = tblActivity.RoomID
Where tblActivity.Time Between 10 And 11
And  tblActivity.RoomID is NULL 
GROUP BY tblActivity.RoomID , tblRoom.RoomType
```

Sorry the questions title is pretty vague. Didnt really know how to explain it. Here it goes - In here I am trying to display Rooms that are not in use at the time between 10 and 11 how can  I get this to display?

The question itself - List the rooms that are not used between 10 and 11 in the morning. (5)
The error Message :  Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column 'tblActivity.Time' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: What type is the `Time` column? What is stored in there?

Comment: Could you include CREATE TABLE statements for tblRoom and tblActivity?

Comment: The time , integers i.e. 10 , 11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your logic, you would seem to want `not exists`:

```
Select r.*
from tblRoom r
where not exists (select 1
                  from tblActivity a
                  where r.ID = a.RoomID and
                        a.Time >= 10 and
                        a.Time <= 11
                 );
```

When using date/times, it is usually better to use explicit comparisons rather than `between`, because the results of `between` can depend on the type of the column.  (This is particularly true for `date`/`datetime` comparisons, but I would just get in the habit and not use it for `time` as well.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this message keeps on coming up : Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

Comment: @elmashrafi . . . I changed the comparisons to be the same as in your question.  You would appear to be storing `Time` as an integer rather than as a `Time`.

Answer (score 0):

`Where tblActivity.Time Between 10 And 11` is identical to writing :

```
Where tblActivity.Time >= 10 And tblActivity.Time <= 11
```

Note that the between in SQL Server is `inclusive`, meaning the end (11) is included in the answer... which is overall considered a bad practice for many good reasons. So be aware it might not always be the case and you could have surprises when changing database engines.

*Why are inclusive ranges a bad practice?*

When you have to partition results, you will prefer to have an algorithm to work with exclusive ranges like `X >= 0 and X < 10` then `X >= 10 and X < 20` instead of inclusive `X >= 0 and X <= 9` then `X >= 10 and X <= 19`.

The inclusive range means you will have to deal with the smaller granular unit of your data to know what is 9 compared to 10. This is easy with simple algorithms, but can become a hell when you have to deal with a complex schema. The smallest unit of an integer is 1, this is easy, but what is the smallest unit of a Date, or a Float?

Comment: Could you please include some of the many reasons why `between` is considered a bad practice?

Comment: @elmashrafi : I am answering your question by explaining how between works. Your problem can't be solved unless you give more information about your schema and data.

Comment: In response to your edit: in order to get date/times for today using `between` one could do: `select ... from tbl where datetimefield between '2015-11-27 00:00:00' and '2015-11-27 23:59:59'`. Identical way of writing the same query would be `where datetimefield >= '2015-11-27 00:00:00' and datetimefield <= '2015-11-27 23:59:59'`. I do like your example about floats though.

Comment: @zedfoxus : But you still have to know your `unit of time`, you decided to go for the second, but maybe later you'll want it to be a millisecond and that will change your whole code instead of just one field. What happens if the date stored is `2015-11-27 23:59:59.500` internally ?

Comment: Ah, I understand your point better now. Thank you. For reference: [Aaron Bertrand has an article about that too](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common). When datatype's lowest denominator is known, I'm likely to use `between`.

Answer (score 0):

That error isn't because of the `between` command.  The error means that if you're using a `group by`, then every field in your `select` list has to either be one of the fields that you're grouping by or it has to be an aggregate field (`sum`, `avg`, `max` and so on).

You could correct that error by adding `sum(tblActivity.Time)` to your `group by` like this

```
Select tblActivity.RoomID, tblActivity.Time , tblRoom.RoomType
from tblActivity
Inner Join tblRoom
On tblRoom.ID = tblActivity.RoomID
Where tblActivity.Time Between 10 And 11
And  tblActivity.RoomID is NULL 
GROUP BY tblActivity.RoomID , tblRoom.RoomType, tblActivity.Time
```

However, even with that fix, I don't think this query is going to give you what you're looking for.  What you're really looking for is a list of all rows in tblRoom where there's no row in tblActivity for the same room with a time between 10 and 11.  That will be a different query than what you have written.

Answer (score -1):

Between Statement Using SQL 
Query is  :

```
Select * from Table Name from Field Name 
between Value1 And Value2
```

Date & Value Applied Possible